# How do I handle SPARQL duplicate specific values?

Tags: duplicates, sparql

```
SELECT ?s ?data ?pro ?o
WHERE {
?s rdf:type rdfs:Class .
?data rdf:type ?s .
pro rdf:type rdf:Property .
?data ?pro ?o .}
```

This SPARQL result is as follows:

```
?s    ?data    ?pro    ?o
A1    B1       A1.a     0
A1    B1       A1.b     0
A1    B1       A1.c     1
A1    B1       A1.d     1
A2    B2       A2.a     0
A2    B2       A2.b     0
.
.
.
```

The result I want is

```
A1    B1       A1.a     0
               A1.b     0
               A1.c     1
               A1.d     1
A2    B2       A2.a     0
               A2.b     0
.
.
.
```

Is this possible?
I understand that DISTINCT is not the solution I want.
Thank you. Happy New Year

Comment: not possible, that is the job of the client consuming the SPARQL resultset and rendering it for a user

Comment: Can you please read ["What should I keep out of my posts and titles?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131009/997587) and apply what you learn to improve your post? As instructed in [ask], can you please describe your problem **_before_** showing code?